Multi-Tenant Setup in Astro
I am starting to play around with Astro(https://astro.build/) and I am super happy so far.
I am trying to build a multi-tenant website with 80+ different designs for one site. Markup should be mostly the same just the static files like logo.svg, favicon.ico, CSS and JS should alterate over the diverent sites.
As I was playing around I started to put my static files (.scss, .ico, .svg) in the /asset folder and wanted to reference them in the astro-components in the /pages folder. My folder structure looks like this right now:

I think its very useful to use the import at the --- Block at the beginning of the component because all the static files will be minified, cachebusted, etc automatically by vite. This is quiete nice and I want to use this feature for sure.
But unfortunately I didnt find a solution yet to reference this static-files dynamically dependend on the incoming Request-Params. I was thinking about something like: If client X requests use this logo, css, etc., if client Y requests use another one.
I tried to use this import-Statements to add static files in my astro-comoponents:
---
import "../../assets/client1/css/_variables.scss";
import Header from "../../components/HeaderWhiteWidow.astro";
import headerLogo from "../../assets/client1/images/logo.svg";
import HtmlMeta from "../../components/HtmlMeta.astro";
import favicon from "../../assets/client1/images/favicon.ico";
import AuthorLayout from '../../pagesBase/Author.astro';
---

<AuthorLayout>
    <HtmlMeta slot="html-meta" faviconHref={favicon} />
    <Header slot="header" logo={headerLogo.src}/>
</AuthorLayout>

I already tried to find a way by saving some client-identifier from Request in the locals-contenxt  and parameterize the import-statemate like this: import logo from ../assets/${clientName}/logo.svg . But as the components are pre-built it is not possible like this.
I started to build for each client its own page in the /pages folder which is super redundant and I want to prevent:

Is there a way to generate the path to static files dynamically, depending on the url and still have the benefit of using the static-files optimization in build?
Maybe there is also another approach for achieving a multi-client setup as described?

Just to be sure, you are in static-site generation mode for those pages (that's the default), not server-side-rendering, right? And what are the urls for the different tenants: different domains or different paths? (P.S. better post code and directory layouts as text instead of screenshots)

Yes, so far I am using the default. The different tenants are differing by the host. www.client1.de/author and www.client2.de/author

Since your tenants live on completely different domains (tenant1.com, tenant2.com, etc.), what you effectively are looking for is to build one complete static site for each tenant.
I would probably use an environment variable. To develop locally:
TENANT=tenant1 npm run dev

And use it like:
import logoTenant1 from "../../assets/tenant1/images/logo.svg";
import logoTenant2 from "../../assets/tenant2/images/logo.svg";

const tenant = import.meta.env.TENANT

const getLogoUrl = () => {
  switch(tenant) {
    case 'tenant1': return logoTenant1
    case 'tenant2': return logoTenant2
  }
}
---

<header>
  <img src={getLogoUrl()} alt={tenant} />
  <p>All tenant-independent markup</p>
</header>

To build all sites, you'll have to adjust your build script to run the following command X times: TENANT=tenantX npm run build in X different directories. But this will depend on your static site hosting service. Finally, you may want to look into building only one tenant if the content for only one tenant changes.

P.S. Just for completeness: instead of using environmental variables, you could consider using Astro.rewrite to rewrite tenant1.com/* to myapp.com/tenant1/*. If you were running a server anyway (i.e. server-side-rendering), perhaps this would have benefits. But then a lot of relative URLs would break, and doesn't seem to be simpler for the static site generation use-case anyway.

Actually thats not what I wanted to achieve... Its more about how to structure the folders and how to cut the pages to prevent to have a lot of duplicate code.

not sure I understand. that's exactly how you avoid duplicating the code for every tenant. (I added a line of code to the example markup)
